# jQuery add CSS instead of replace? or set multiple?

Tags: jquery, css

I wanted to do

```
$('.place').css('background', 'url(open.png) left top no-repeat, url(close.png) bottom right no-repeat');
```

However jquery doesnt like the ','. Making it two lines has the 2nd css replace the css on the first line. How do i set the css so it will have both open and close background image?

Comment: How do you want to have two background images on the same element? That is not possible and doesn't make any sense... What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: it is possible and make sense. One is at the topleft and the other is bottom right. It works in regular css but in certain circumstance i need this css to be different.

Comment: +1 - it's good to know that CSS3 supports multiple background images

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be easiest to use the [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/). Since your using css3 i think that would be the only way for you to add it. and just create a css class to add.

Answer (score 2):

Having two background images on the same element in CSS is not possible. It is possible with CSS3, but I expect jquery doesn't allow for that yet.

Answer (score 2):

Use plain javascript instead.

```
$('.place').get(0).style.background = 'url(open.png) left top no-repeat, url(close.png) bottom right no-repeat'
```

Answer (score 0):

For your given CSS, jQuery does not do any extra processing. It basically sets:

```
element.style['background'] = ...;
```

See lines [33](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L33) and [77](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L77) in jQuery's source.

A [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/RLfqX/) of setting 2 backgrounds.

Comment: How is using jQuery any easier than writing what you just spelled out?

Comment: @Chase - Where exactly did I say anything about jQuery being any easier?